# Session variable in master page causing error

Tags: asp.net

This line in a script on my master page is causing an error on some pages but not all.

```
    var sessionTimeout = "<%= Session.Timeout %>";
```

The error I'm getting is

The Controls collection cannot be modified because the control contains code blocks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `<%# instead of <%= :`

so like this,

```
var sessionTimeout = "<%# Session.Timeout %>";
```

instead of,

```
var sessionTimeout = "<%= Session.Timeout %>";
```